# Find text before phone number in string regex PHP

Tags: php, regex

So I have this list of strings given to me as follows:

```
David palmer & Betsy Harrell 229-548-9651 Emily
```

I know how to get the phone number out of that string by doing this:

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{3}[\-][0-9]{3}[\-][0-9]{4}/', $text, $matches);
$matches = $matches[0];
```

But I need to get the name before hand AND the phone number. This is a bit beyond my regex knowledge. So I need

```
David palmer & Betsy Harrell
```

and

```
229-548-9651
```

Comment: Just prepend `.*` to your regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing groups to get two substrings:

```
$s = 'David palmer & Betsy Harrell 229-548-9651 Emily';
if (preg_match('~^(.*?)\s*(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})~', $s, $m)) {
  echo $m[1] . "\n" . $m[2];
}
```

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/REsvJD).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first...
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})` - date pattern (3 digits, `-`, 3 digits, `-`, 4 digits).

Note you do not need to put `-` into a character class, and no need to escape it outside a character class. `\d` is equal to `[0-9]` if you do not use any specific modifiers/PCRE verbs related to Unicode.